# Validate uniqueness for multiple columns individually

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `user` model with `username` and `nickname` fields. What I want to do is to create a `validations` rule that can check uniqueness for both fields individually, not as a combination (or scope I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
validate do |r|
  if where("username LIKE ? OR nickname LIKE ?", r.username, r.username).first
    r.errors.add :username, "is already taken"
  end

  if where("username LIKE ? OR nickname LIKE ?", r.nickname, r.nickname).first
    r.errors.add :nickname, "is already taken"
  end
end
```

Comment: I guess there is no built-in support to specifying column names for uniqueness validation to look for it. I can use this and create a custom validation class.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The only thing you can do is to make a column unique on a scope. Lets say you have `first_name` and `last_name`. You could specify that first_name has to be unique on the same last_name. So `John Doe` and `John Foe` could coexist but not twice `John Doe`. This would be done with `validates :first_name, :uniqueness, :scope => :last_name`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do this?

```
validates :username, :uniqueness => true
validates :nickname, :uniqueness => true
```

Comment: I want username to be unique in both `username` and `nickname` fields. The same goes for nickname.

Comment: Oh that was not clear from your question. So your saying you don't want someone to enter a username that already exists in another persons username or nickname?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant.